# Prove $ST = 0 \implies ST^* = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

**EDIT - checking if it is better now**

So I have some proof and I'm not sure on one of the transitions.

---

**In this same assignment we had to prove the following:**

Let V a Hermitian vector space and $T:V \to V$ is normal in $V$. Prove $T,T^*$ have the same kernel and Image.

**Using the above theorem I solved the current question:**

Let V a Hermitian vector space $T:V \to V$ is normal in $V$ and $S:V \to V$ is linear. Prove $ST=0 \implies ST^* = 0$.

---

**My proof is this:**

Suppose $ST=0$. Since $T$ is normal in $V$ and $V$ is Hermitian:

we have Ker$T$ = Ker$T^*$ and Im$T$=Im$T^*$.

Let some $v \in V$ then from the datum $ST(v)=0$. We have 2 options:

1. $T(v) = 0 \implies S(T(v)) = S(0) = 0$
2. $T(v) = u \neq 0 \in V,\;S(u) = 0$

For case #1 since we have Ker$T$=Ker$T^*$ then: $T(v) = 0 \iff T^*(v) = 0$ we can derive $ST = 0 \implies ST^* = 0$

For case #2 we have $ST = 0 \implies$ Im$T \subseteq$ Ker$S$. Using Im$T$ = Im$T^*$ we can deduce Im$T^* \subseteq$ Ker$S$ therfore implying $ST^*=0$

All in all we have $ST=0 \implies ST^* = 0$

Comment: $ST=0 \iff \operatorname{im} T \subseteq \ker S \iff \operatorname{im} T^* \subseteq \ker S \iff ST^*=0$

Comment: I am not following the last step: from $T(v) = 0 \iff T^*(v) = 0$ you have that $T(v) = u' \neq 0$ but it does not follow that $u'=u$ or $S(u')=0$.

Comment: AsiMathStudent I just wanted to say that I'm missing a logical step in between your second last line and your last line. Basically @azif00 's comment fills this gap. You need statements about $\operatorname{ker} S$, not $\operatorname{ker} T$.

Comment: @Targon yes I just erased my comment because I guess I misunderstood your question thank you very much there is a step missing!

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, and this statement is not true in general for non-normal operators. Let $\{e_0, e_1, \dots\}$ be a basis for your Hilbert space and consider the shift operator $T(e_i) = e_{i+1}$ and $S(e_i) = 0\ \forall\ i>0$ then $ST=0$, I'll leave it to you to figure out $T^*$ and see that the composition is not zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the help!